# PHP Session refusing to update variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I have been looking around for a good minute and I learned using the Header() function is supposed to destroy the session so you can reload it again, which I do. Its called and the SQL is updated but the session refuses to update until I relog into the account.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes. In case if your CURL is slow and is loading too much (Can be IPv6 problem)

error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID', 'X');
define('OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET', 'X');

$authorizeURL = 'X';
$tokenURL = 'X';
$apiURLBase = 'X';
$apiURLConnectionBase = 'X';
$steamID = "";
$tempUsername = "";

session_start(); 

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";


    $curXP= $_SESSION["CommunityCurrentExp"];
    $maxXP= $_SESSION["CommunityMaxExp"];
    $userID= $_SESSION["id"];

    if(session('access_token')) {
      $user = apiRequest($apiURLBase);
      $userConnections = apiRequest($apiURLConnectionBase);

        foreach($userConnections as $key => $value) {
            if($userConnections[$key]->type == "steam") {
                    $steamID = $userConnections[$key]->id;
            }
          }

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET 
            steamid = ?, 
            DiscordUsername = ? 
            WHERE id = ?";

              if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Set parameters
                $param_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];
                $param_discordusername = $user->username;
                $param_steamid = $steamID;


                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $param_steamid, $param_discordusername, $param_id);



                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    // Password updated successfully. Destroy the session, and redirect to login page
                    header("location: console.php");
                } else { 
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later." + mysqli_error($link); 
                }

                // Close statement
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }


        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
```

Technically this should update all the information I have but it only is updated once, when logging in.

Comment: "I learned using the Header() function is supposed to destroy the session"...no, `header("location...` just redirects the browser to another URL. It has nothing to do with sessions.

Comment: Anyway I don't see anywhere in the code where you try to update the session. Can you be clearer about exactly what you are trying to achieve and what is going wrong, and give a clear step-by-step outline of the behaviour of the code? Your description is a bit vague, to say the least.

Comment: @ADyson If the user changes their username, or updates the database and reloads the page, it is still showing their old username. In order to get it to show your new updated name, you have to relog. Is there a way to make it grab new session information on page refresh?

Comment: Yes but first you have to actually update the session with the new username information. Your code doesn't do that - that was my point.

Comment: @ADyson Im aware of that. I looked into the session api on the PHP website and there isn't a session_refresh() that works in that way. I was under the impression header was the way to refresh those variables, so since we are both on the same page that my code is not working... What is it that I need to do..? A link or a statement would be useful.

Comment: To set or update a session value it's just a variable assignment. E.g. `$_SESSION["username"] = "something";`. Surely you must have set them like that originally during the login process?

Comment: @ADyson That was it, I realize how this works now and I appreciate you setting that straight for me. Everything works now after I set the sessions variable